# jQuery find url within string and wrap with href if not already wrapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to wrap href around matched urls within an imported string - however in some cases the urls already have the href attribute set therefore they do not need wrapping. My code at this early stage is as follows

```
if(jQuery('.single-ai1ec_event')) {
        var httpSelector = '.single-ai1ec_event .entry-content, .single-ai1ec_event .p-location';
        var searchText = jQuery(httpSelector).text();
        var expression = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
        var urls = searchText.match(expression);
        var wrappedUrl;
        if (urls) {
            for (var i = 0, il = urls.length; i < il; i++) {
                jQuery(httpSelector).html(function () {
                    wrappedUrl = wrap(urls[i]);
                    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace(urls[i], wrappedUrl));
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function wrap(str) {
        return '<a href="' + str + '" target="_blank">' + str + '<\/a>';
    }
```

I am currently looking for a way to exclude wrapping urls that aleady have the href attribute set but without much success.

Comment: What if we add a check that we are not inside `<a>` tag: `var expression = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?(?!(?:[^>]*?>)?[^<]*?<\/a>)/gi;`? See https://regex101.com/r/oZ7jE4/3

Comment: Exactly.. that would be a better approach..

Comment: Perhaps, `*:not([href])` can do as well in the selector.

Comment: Thanks - I have implemented the regex and this so far seems to work great - will continue testing

Answer (score 1):

You can change your selector to exclude anchors with no href tag like this:

```
:not([href])
```

so then your selector becomes:

```
var httpSelector = 'a:not([href]).single-ai1ec_event ...';
```